# Message from car to remove my key and it won't start

Tags: starting, mercedes-benz

I have a Mercedes Benz C250 and every time I attempt to start the car I get a message to remove my key from the ignition and the car wont turn over. I have change out the battery and I have completed a turn up but yet it still won't start. How do I get my car to start? What's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

This is very common for many MB models. You did not provide your year but I'm going to assume its the w204 (07-15 c class) which is the most trouble prone C class model.

**The most common reasons for no start on these with the message you are receiving:**

1. There is dirt blocking the IR signal on your KEY or the EIS. Try to clean the red plastic spot on your key and on the EIS.
2. The key is damaged. If you shake it do you hear anything rattle? Try another key if you have one. You can also order a new key from MB.
3. The EIS and KEY have lost synchronization.
4. and finally, the MOST common. The ESL (electronic steering lock) has gone bad. Typically the motor in them fail.

If cleaning the key and EIS does not work, I suggest you find a good independent MB shop to fix things for you. Problems 2-4 are not DIY capable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your vehicle and key have become unpaired.  In other words, your car no longer recognizes the key as a valid one to start the car.

Unless you have a 2nd key which works, you may be at the mercy of your local Mercedes dealer who should be able to either re-pair that key to the car or pair up a new one.